# Spring Kafka Consumer Client-Id configuration

Tags: spring-kafka

I am where i have two Kafka Listener components, each listening to a different topic and expecting a different payload.
My question is, can i use the same client-id for both or does it have to be different? If the client-id has to be different i am wanting to understand a use-case where the client-id can be effectively used.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> An id string to pass to the server when making requests. The purpose of this is to be able to track the source of requests beyond just ip/port by allowing a logical application name to be included in server-side request logging.

So, technically you really can have the same value for different consumers/producers

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. However, spring-kafka is forcing me to use different client-ids for my two kafka listeners as it says it has to be unique.

Comment: It throws an error "Another endpoint is already registered with id" in class KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry (Line 152)

Comment: `@KafkaListener.id()`? Do you see somewhere a pointer that this bean id is mapped to the `client-id` ? You should really use `ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG` directly.

Comment: So when i use the ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, that would give the consumer a logical name no matter how many topics it listens too, right?
Also, can you please briefly explain what  KafkaListener.id() is used for?

Comment: Yes, that is how that property works. The topics amount is fully unrelated. That it a `Consumer` indicator for the Kafka broker. That's fully not related to the listener though

Comment: So i set the CLIENT_ID_CONFIG property to the hostname but now i see exceptions in the logs.
`javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: kafka.consumer:type=app-info,id=nycupdevceapp02.activehealth.loc
 at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437) ~[?:1.7.0_80]
 at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898) ~[?:1.7.0_80]`

Comment: Hm. Try to disable JMX for Kafka then. Or, that looks like a bug from the Kafka perspective and we can't use the same `client.id` for several Consumers...