# Kafka client id property with spring cloud stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

With Spring Cloud Stream is there any way to set the Kafka client id property? Naturally I'm using the Kafka binder. Several of my services that would set this will be replicated, so is there any way to make the IDs unique between instances? (Looking at [Spring Kafka Consumer Client-Id configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173712/spring-kafka-consumer-client-id-configuration) it appears that the IDs need to be unique.)

Assuming I can set the property, is there anyway to query for the ID at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it via `clientId` property of *KafkaProperties* provided by *[spring-kafka](https://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/)* project (which is used by spring-cloud-stream). 
That said, I am not sure I fully understand the "*... replicated services...*" remark. I mean I am not sure what do you mean by that in the scope of spring-cloud-stream project and what it may or may not support.
Could you please clarify?

Comment: The services are running as Docker services and are replicated so that there are multiple copies of the service running at once. Sorry for the ambiguity.